# What will be the value of AR and MA order?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, arima

I want to determine the value of p and q of ARIMA model from the ACF and PACF plot given bellow. What will be the order and why? 
[image: ACF and PACF plot]

Comment: This is a FAQ: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+order+acf+pacf.